# Java Servlet java.lang.NullPointerException at doGet()

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, servlets, tomcat9

I have an HTTP 500 - Internal server error for java servlet. And I didn’t found a solution on forums for my case. I’m using IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3 and Apache Tomcat Server 9.0.43. Here’s my projet files structure and my code. I have been looking for a solution for 3 hours now. Please,I need help.
[image: files structure]

The servlet class

```
package com.sdzee.servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name="Test",value="/test2")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/../../main/webapp/test.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }

}
```

the `test.jsp` file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>JSP test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the servlet definition in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sdzee.servlets.Test</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>Auteur</param-name>
            <param-value>Moi</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and the results :
[image]

Comment: The `main` directory isn't there at runtime. Have a look at what is actually in your WAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think getRequestDispatcher("/../../main/webapp/test.jsp") should be getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp")

Comment: Yes it works, thank you so much. But I wouldlike to understand why just ("/test.jsp") as files are not in the same folder.

Comment: The parameter is a url, not a path to a file. You could also surf to `http://localhost:8080/test.jsp` and open the jsp without passing through your servlet.